# Does Kubernetes restart a failed container or create a new container when the running container fails for any reason?

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have ran a docker container locally and it stores data in a file (currently no volume is mounted). I stored some data using the API. After that I failed the container using `process.exit(1)` and started the container again. The previously stored data in the container survives (as expected). But when I do this same thing in Kubernetes (minikube) the data is lost.

Comment: "*Servers are cattles, not pets*" - terminate the sick one, get a new one. Hence, if a container is "sick" (for any reason), it gets terminated and a new (identical*) container replaces it. *Keep in mind that containers should be stateless - thas is one of the reasons why. --- How is the question related to node.js?

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki for better visibility, feel free to edit and expand it.

As described in comments, kubernetes replaces failed containers with new (identical) ones and this explain why container's filesystem will be clean.

Also as said containers should be stateless. There are different options how to run different applications and take care about its data:

- [Run a stateless application using a Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/)
- Run a stateful application either as a [single instance](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/) or as a [replicated set](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/)
- [Run automated tasks with a CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/)

Useful links:

- [Kubernetes workloads](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/)
- [Pod lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/)